# Xamarin.iOS UITesting - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ui-testing, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I ve been experimenting with Xamarin UI Testing on iOS for a while now and everything works as expected, except from the screenshots part. When doing app.Screenshot("First"); I get the following error message:

> System.Exception : Error while performing Screenshot("First")
>   ----> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path  "/screenshot-1.png" is denied.

I have searched everywhere on the web, but I could not find a way to overcome this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S: I have also run Xamarin Studio with administrator privileges but again with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error was first seen when updating to `iOS` 10.x.

1. In your iOS app, make sure that the `Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent` package is updated to `0.20.3` (latest version).
2. In your `UITest` project, make sure that `Xamarin.UITest` package is updated to the latest stable `2.x` version (currently `2.0.5`, I am using pre-release `2.0.5.1590-dev`) and the `NUnit` package is updated to version `2.6.4` from the default `2.6.3` (but **not** update to NUnit `3.x`)
3. Enable local screenshot saving via `.EnableLocalScreenshots()`

   ConfigureApp.iOS.EnableLocalScreenshots().StartApp();

Note: Assuming you have done this due to the error you are getting....

Comment: Downgrading NUnit to 2.6.4 worked for me @SushiHangover!
Thank you very much!

Comment: @SushiHangover Is there any reason why the latest versions of NUnit are not supported?

Comment: @MarioGalván There are compatibility issues as Nunit 3.0+ introduced breaking changes from Nunit 2.x and thus Xamarin Studio / UITest are still using 2.6.3/2.6.4 to prevent breaking client's current testing code. There are some bugzilla issues concerning this and I have seen NUnit 3.0 PRs in some of the code base, but the real answer on when 3.0 will have full support is one for Xamarin. ;-/  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/installing-nunit-using-nuget/

Comment: Thanks that sounds reasonable :)